# WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location '...' but it is not a conda environment. Continue creating environment (y/[n])?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I removed a Conda environment with this line

```
conda env remove -n myenv
```

And tried to replace it by creating a new one

```
conda create -n myenv
```

And it get this warning:

> WARNING: A directory already exists at the target location '...' but it is not a conda environment. Continue creating environment (y/[n])?

It seems like the first command doesn't remove the folder of the environment, even though the environment is deleted.

**When removing an environment, is there a way to delete the folder so this warning doesn't pop up?**

Comment: Do you have any files in there that can't be deleted by your user account?

Comment: That's possible. It's a corporate PC.

Answer (score 2):

If you open up an Anaconda Prompt and type in
`conda info`
You should see a section that has `envs directories` and if you go to the first file path specified under "envs directories" in your file explorer, you should see a list of the conda virtual environments you've created, with a directory for each venv. For example, my file path to find it is C:\Users<myusername>\anaconda3\envs

From there, you should be able to find the directory that corresponds to the old virtual environment, and delete it.

Comment: While this solution worked for me (thanks for that!), it still doesn't explain why 'conda env remove -n myenv' doesn't remove the directory of the old environment.